# Help with I.V.P

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

is the I.V.P:

$$\begin{cases}
\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\sin(e^{y})\\[8pt]
y(0)=a
\end{cases}
\text{ where } a\in \mathbb{R}$$

a) Prove that the equation has unique solution $y(x,a)$ and the maximum range is $\langle- \infty, \infty\rangle$

b) Prove: $|y(x,a)-a |\le x$

---

I have tried to solve the equation $$\int \frac{dy}{\sin(e^{y})}=\int dx$$ for starters but no solution. any idea how to start?

Comment: please define variables,it would be more better,so both involves  $x$ right

Comment: no not  $x+c$,it is  just $dx$,use  $x$ when integrate,not before

Comment: i think there is no   solution in elementary functions

Comment: mmm .. then the problem is incorrect?

Comment: no it involves hyperbolic functions,let us wait for other guys

Comment: Clearly b) is false for $x<0$.

Comment: but how to find the only solution y(x)?

Comment: $\displaystyle \int\frac{dy}{\sin e^y} = \int e^{-y} \frac{e^y\,dy}{\sin e^y} = \int\frac 1 u \frac{du}{\sin u}$.  If I weren't busy with other things at this moment, I might think about whether this could be done by parts.

Comment: P.V.I is what?  Initial Value Problem?

Comment: @GEdgar In some latin languages I.V.P. translates to P.V.I..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to solve the nonlineal ODE....

The problem is $y'=f(x, y(x))$ with $y(0)=a$ and $f(x, y(x))=\sin(e^y)$.

a) As $f(x, y)$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}f(x, y)=\cos(e^y)e^y$ are continuous functions for all $(x,y)\in\Bbb{R}^2$, from the Existence and Uniqueness Theorem it follows that there exists a unique solution $y(x)$ for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$.

b) Observe that
$$
y(x,a)=y(0)+\int_0^x f(t,y(t))\operatorname{d}t
$$
and thus
$$
|y(x,a)-a|=\left|\int_0^x f(t,y(t))\operatorname{d}t\right|\le \int_0^x \left|f(t,y(t))\right|\operatorname{d}t=x\qquad x\ge 0
$$
because $\left|f(t,y(t))\right|=\left|\sin(e^y)\right|=1$.

Comment: right! it must be $x\ge 0$. Or better $|y(x,a)−a|\le |x|$.

Comment: thanks, but as I can find the values ​​of "a" such that y(x,a)= 0? would be using the formula in part b)?

Comment: I try this: $$y(x,a)=0=a+\int_{0}^{x}f(t,y(t))dt$$
$$a=-\int_{0}^{x}f(t,y(t))dt$$ is correct?